# Woocommerce Checkout Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to use multidimensional input fields in woocommerce checkout, I've added all of the fields but when I submit checkout it gives me an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Given below is my code:

```
<div class="col_1">
    <h5> Guest Name <span style="color:red"> * </span> </h5>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="tm_guests[1][tm_order_meta_guest_name]" placeholder="" value="">

    <h5> Contact Number </h5>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="tm_guests[1][tm_order_meta_contact_number]" placeholder="" value="">

    <h5> Date of birth </h5>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="tm_guests[1][tm_order_meta_dob]" placeholder="" value="">
</div>
```

I have checked if everything else is working fine by removing the multidimensional inputs and it works fine, but its not working with multidimensional inputs

The reason for me to do this is that I am cloning these fields via jQUery on frontend, so there would be X number of guests

Comment: If it's WooCommerce then the data should be post in an array not JSON.  What other code have you got processing the fields?

Comment: And how do you try to add these fields? The correct way is using special hooks and `woocommerce_form_field()` function https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/checkout-fields.html#create_checkout_field

Comment: Almost fixed it myself. Will post a solution. Thanks for help guys